# How can I save the Values in edittext boxes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, save

I have an app where you upload images to a server. My problem is the user enters their email password and client ID in edittext boxes these are then used for URL building.
I want to save the information entered into the edittext boxes so the user doesn't have to retype it every time.
Oly answered that I can find on SO  to save the values to a textView ETC. I want the values to be saved in the edittext boxes

**code where the text boxes are called and passed to another activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password, id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
        password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
        id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);
        Button loginBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAddress=email.getText().toString().trim();
                String userPassword=password.getText().toString().trim();
                String clientId=id.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
    CameraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("clientId", clientId);
                intent.putExtra("email", emailAddress);
                intent.putExtra("password", userPassword);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: use Singleton class'

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Sorry I hate to be this guy, I have only been developing for android and coding in genereal for about two weeks, I dont understand what you mean please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String PASS = "pass";
    private SharedPreferences mPreference;
    private EditText email, password, id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
        password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
        id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);
        Button loginBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);

        mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        id.setText(mPreference.getString(ID, ""));
        email.setText(mPreference.getString(EMAIL, ""));
        password.setText(mPreference.getString(PASS, ""));

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAddress=email.getText().toString().trim();
                String userPassword=password.getText().toString().trim();
                String clientId=id.getText().toString().trim();

                mPreference.edit().putString(ID, clientId).apply();
                mPreference.edit().putString(EMAIL, emailAddress).apply();
                mPreference.edit().putString(PASS, userPassword).apply();

                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
    CameraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("clientId", clientId);
                intent.putExtra("email", emailAddress);
                intent.putExtra("password", userPassword);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At what time you want these values to be populated??

When user get back to the same activity or when user kills the activity and reopen your app??

Please tell

Comment: Thank you for , trying to help, The questions has been answered

Comment: No worries, sharedpreference is kind of session scope in android.